# Change current percentage of an infinite running CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I want to create a very **basic** **slider** on my own. The sliding works like a charm, is infinite, but I would like to allow the user to skip/back to the specific neighbours (e.g. arrows).

```
@keyframes slider-ani {
  0% { left: 33.3%; }
  20% { left: 33.3%; }
  25% { left: 0%; }
  45% { left: 0%; }
  50% { left: -33.3%; }
  70% { left: -33.3%; }
  100% { left: 33.3%; }
}
```

Is there a way to maybe put a Javascript command, telling the running animation to go to the next step, e.g. 25% to 45%.

I would like to use as much CSS3 as possible. I know this is easy to be done in jQuery.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/j10gqfk5/)

Comment: Well it's not much more than this. But anyway, I added a jsfiddle. =)

Comment: I feel this would be tough to achieve with CSS and just arrows but in any case do you need the sliding to continue after the forward/backward jump happens after clicking the arrow?

Comment: Well clicking an arrow shall just go the next percentage value. The animation should continue then.

Comment: You can't make it skip to the next percentage value as far as I am aware, the only thing that can be achieved is a manual positioning.

Comment: Okay, but I found this one. https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes That seems to work on keyframe via jQuery. Do you think that could be worth a test? =)

Comment: Maybe. They are doing a lot of stuff like pause play state, resume it etc and I can't think of anyway to do those operations with a single click and only using CSS.

Comment: Mhh well because I just need to skip and so on. I don't think this plugin will help me. Alright. Found this one here http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/ I think I just do it in that way without keyframes. Thank you anyway :) And maybe CSS support that in the future natively.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I had in mind when I asked you if animation should continue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with CSS and radio buttons (without keyframes). This is great because it runs without jQuery and natively on any device. But it's way harder to create it.

[image: the final result]